# Setting DataContext in XAML to Window or a property of the Window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When we are setting DataContext inside XAML to a ViewModel, we use either this:

```
 <Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
```

or binding it inside a tag to a StaticResource. 
(Assuming someone doesn't use a framework like Prism)

But, is it possible to set the DataContext via XAML

1. to the Window itself (not a seperate ViewModel class)

In other words, how can you define this C# code in XAML:

```
DataContext = this;
```

2. or to a property of the Window? (for example, if we want to change the DataContext temporarely to something else only for a single Control like TextBox)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You can set a `Window`'s `DataContext` to the `Window` itself like that (Add that line to your `Window`'s properties in the XAML):

   **DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"**
2. After binding the `Window` to itself as `DataContext`, you can already use the properties of the `Window`, so you may not need to bind to a property.